# Git errors, cannot spawn/unable to fork off index-pack

Tags: git, git-for-windows

I'm getting these two errors when trying to clone my repo via SSH.

```
remote: Counting objects: 304517, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (97849/97849), done.
error: cannot spawn git: No error
fatal: fetch-pack: unable to fork off index-pack
```

I've installed 2 versions of Git, same issue.  Tried cloning to different folder, same issue.  Tried cloning to different folder on different drive, same issue.

When trying to clone via https:

Any ideas?

Comment: "cannot spawn git" suggests that you're either out of memory or your Git is installed improperly. I don't use Windows so can't say more here—on a Unix/Linux box you'd get details like "out of memory" or "too many processes" or whatever it is that's actually gone wrong, as a clue to what resource has run out.